# Can data contract serialization be used with BasicHttpBinding?

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontractserializer, xmlserializer, basichttpbinding

If I want to write a web service and expose it as both WCF and basic SOAP, can my data types use only data contract serialization or do I have to use the XmlSerializer?

[Microsoft mentions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx) that the XmlSerializer is required

> When creating services that follow the legacy SOAP Encoding standard

which may imply this.

Is there a standard technique for creating data types that can be exposed through all bindings?

Comment: It did not worked for me , After replacing wit [DataContract], it started throwing error like The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter.... http://tempuri.org/:MySomeMethodResult. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 2647. 'EndElement' 'MySomeMethodResult' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' is not expected. Expecting element '_x003C_MyPropertyName_x003E_k__BackingField'.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can completely ignore the old XML Serializer if you are creating a new service. Just use Data Contract Serialization and the binding will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could decorate your types with both data and xml serialization attributes. They will both be applied depending on the context.